# IntelliJ IDEA can't find project sdk

Tags: java, intellij-idea

It shows I have no sdk, but I have installed java development kit already:

[image: It shows I have no sdk, but I have installed java development kit already.]

I am new in programming world.

Comment: At the very top of your image, where it says `<No SDK>` in the dropdown menu, what are your options?

Comment: See the "New" button up there on the right?

Comment: @Sam I haven't any option there

Comment: @Zisan What about what assylias said? What happens when you click the `New` button?

Comment: @sam It shows "select home directory for jdk".

Comment: @Sam I go into c/java , but which one I need to select? jdk or jre?

Comment: @Zisan Use the JDK

Comment: Yeah, I have solved the problem. Thanks a lot brothers. I have just created this account in stackoverflow. so I haven't much knowledge about how to use it. I am gonna watch tutorial .  have a nice day brothers !!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks brother @Sam

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to tell the system where to find the SDK. [This](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html) explains how to set this variable on Windows.

Additionally you should add `$JAVA_HOME/bin` (the binary directory of your Java SDK) to your path environment variable.